# All contact names on device changed without user intervention

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, contacts

All of the contact names stored on my device got changed to ***"1 Null"*** without my intervention.
How can I get them back? Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Did you try some other contacts app?

Comment: What did you do that might have led to this situation? Anything you remember between when it worked last time and then started being like in that screenshot? Like: installed some other app, tried to sync with something, experienced a sudden device shutdown/crash…